# path setting for c++ include headers for vim

Tags: c++, vim, path, include

My vim has path settings as shown below.

```
path=.,/usr/include,,
```

I think this is a default setting of 'path' I guess.

Because of this, <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> opens c header files under the cursor.

But on C++ file C++ header files are not opened because the C++ header file location is not added to `path` variable of vim.

```
set path+=/usr/include/c++/4.6
```

I think that this setting on `vimrc` would be a solution.
But the problem is the actual directory location for C++ header file would be changed in every different linux distributions and g++ compiler versions.

How can I set path for c++ header files in a portable manner?

```
let g:gcpp_headers_path = system("g++ --version | grep g++ | awk '{print \"/usr/include/c++/\"$NF}'")

execute 'set path+=' . g:gcpp_headers_path
```

Now I am using this above:
This works with g++ environment. Not tested with other compilers.

Comment: @zachlatta, Thank you for editing of my question prettier!

Comment: You might grep the search path out of the result of calling `cpp -v`: `awk '/^#include </ { state=1 } /End of search list/ { state=0 } /^ / && state { print substr($0, 2) }'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there's a limited number of locations, a simple conditional in `~/.vimrc` will do:

```
if isdirectory('/usr/include/c++/4.6')
    set path+=/usr/include/c++/4.6
elseif isdirectory(...
```

If you have a lot of different systems, and don't want to maintain all variations in a central place, you can move the system-dependent settings to a separate, local-only file, and invoke that from your `~/.vimrc`, like this:

```
" Source system-specific .vimrc first.
if filereadable(expand('~/local/.vimrc'))
    source ~/local/.vimrc
endif
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this would be a good solution. Thank you.

Comment: The usage of expand() pretty much helped me this time. Thank you!

Comment: seems like a security risk?

Comment: @StevenLu: For arbitrary locations, yes. For the suggested `~/local/.vimrc` (or any other location within your home directory), not.

Comment: let g:gcpp_headers_path = system("g++ --version | grep g++ | awk '{print \"/usr/include/c++/\"$NF}'")

execute 'set path+=' . g:gcpp_headers_path

Now I am using this above:

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same problem, so here is my solution for documentation purposes:

1) I added the following to my `.bashrc`:

```
# add additional search paths to vim.
VIM_EXTPATHS="$HOME/.vim.extpaths"
if [ ! -e "$VIM_EXTPATHS" ] || [ "/usr/bin/cpp" -nt "$VIM_EXTPATHS" ]; then
    echo | cpp -v 2>&1 | \
    awk '/^#include </ { state=1 } /End of search list/ { state=0 } /^ / && state { print "set path+=" substr($0, 2) "/**2" }' > $VIM_EXTPATHS
fi
```

2) I added the following to my `.vimrc`:

```
" add extra paths.
let s:extpaths=expand("$HOME/.vim.extpaths")
if filereadable(s:extpaths)
    execute "source ".s:extpaths
endif
```

On my system, the contents of the `.vim.extpaths` file are as follows:

```
set path+=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include/**2
set path+=/usr/local/include/**2
set path+=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include-fixed/**2
set path+=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/**2
set path+=/usr/include/**2
```

The `**2` means that ViM will search two directories deep inside these directories. Now `gf` will find all the C++ headers I need. If you increase the depth, searches will take a lot more time, so don't set this number too high.

@note: for `#include <chrono>`, ViM will go to `/usr/include/boost/chrono`, which, funny enough, is a directory. I wonder why `go file` will open a directory, maybe this should be reported as a bug. To get to the correct `chrono` header you have to type `2gf`.

Answer (score 0):

The following Vimscript code, intended for a `.vimrc` file, updates `path` to include the search paths used by the preprocessor.

```
if executable('gcc')
  let s:expr = 'gcc -Wp,-v -x c++ - -fsyntax-only 2>&1 | grep "^ " | sed "s/^ //"'
  let s:lines = systemlist(s:expr)
  for s:line in s:lines
    execute 'set path+=' . fnameescape(s:line)
  endfor
endif
```

I have [similar code](https://github.com/dstein64/dotfiles/blob/9785ef242af879a613a9c5b12ce873a5fa8c1a62/packages/vim/.vimrc#L83-L105) in my `.vimrc`, but with additional special-case handling.

Answer (score -2):

There are specific environment variables for the compiler to examine. If you are using gcc/g++ in a linux/Unix environment, then the variables are `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`.  If you are using bash/sh then use `export VARIABLE=value` or if you are using csh/tcsh then use `setenv VARIABLE value` or if you are using some other shell then you will need to look that up. In these examples `VARIABLE` is either `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much but what I need to know is not about the `compiler` but about the editor `vim`.